# Correct AC Compressor for '04 Dodge stratus SE 2.7L 6cyl

Tags: ac, dodge, parts, stratus

Apparently, there are two types of AC compressors for my '04 Dodge Stratus SE, 2.7 liter 6 cylinder engine, and I need to know which one I need.

I tried looking on a parts store, but I couldn't get past which of these:

```
SE -- V6 - 2.7L vin R 167ci 2700cc type EER - MFI GAS DOHC
SE -- V6 - 2.7L vin T 167ci 2700cc - MFI FLEX DOHC
```

it was. How do I distinguish them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you can tell by the vin. It appears to be asking engine code - that's the eighth digit. See if it matches the R or T shown in the part description there, and that should give you your answer.

Comment: Thanks, that did get me further. However, I do know that my car has a 5 groove belt (I was told) and all of the parts listed at http://bit.ly/1LgnAAs except one say 6 pulley belt. Is that the same thing?

Under the compatibility tab, my car is listed under 67340 AND the ones that say 6 pulley.

Sorry, I wish I knew more of what I was talking about lol...

Comment: It says pulley grooves are 6 - so the pulley should then have 5 ridges to fit the 5 grooves in your belt. I think you should be good. But it can be touch and go with aftermarket parts being matched correctly, and sometimes may take a couple of tries to get the correct match.